# Is there a way to just get a list of all the specs in a suite in a jasmine report?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, jasmine-reporters

I need a list of all the specs that are mentioned in a suite from the protractor config file and know how may have failed. Is there a way to achieve this? I am writing a custom jasmine report for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will use something like this in your custom jasmine reporter:

```
var suiteResults = [];
var currentSpecName;
var currentSpecStatus;

specStarted: function(spec) {
    // get the name of the spec
    console.log('Starting Spec: ' + spec.fullName);
    currentSpecName = spec.fullName;
};

specDone: function(result) {
    var passCount = result.passedExpectations.length;
    var failCount = result.failedExpectations.length;
    var expectationCount = passCount + failCount;

    var specIsDisabled = result.status === 'disabled';
    var specIsPending = result.status === 'pending';
    var specIsInvalid = !specIsDisabled && !specIsPending && expectationCount === 0;
    var specPassed = !specIsDisabled && !specIsPending && !specIsInvalid && failCount === 0;
    var specFailed = !specIsDisabled && !specIsPending && !specIsInvalid && !specPassed;    

    currentSpecStatus = specFailed ? 'FAILED' : 'PASSED';
    console.log('Status: ' + currentSpecStatus);
    suiteResults.push({specName: currentSpecName, specStatus: currentSpecStatus});
};

suiteDone: function() {
    var specCount = suiteResults.length;
    var failCount = suiteResults.filter(function(result) {
        return result.specStatus === 'FAILED';
    }).length;
    console.log(specCount + ' specs, ' + failCount + ' failures');
},
```